# Can I change the download path for the Amazon MP3 cloud?

Tags: downloading, mp3-player, amazon-mp3

I want to download my music from the cloud through the Amazon MP3 app, but whenever I download it always puts it in the "amazonmp3" folder on my phone's internal drive. This is kind of annoying because my internal drive is not as big as my perfectly good 16GB SD card plugged in, which I'd much rather put the music on.

I can't find anything in the settings that references the path where music gets downloaded. Even when I move the app itself to the SD card, it still downloads everything to internal storage. Even worse, my phone won't let me easily just move the folders from the internal storage to the SD card; I have to plug it in and connect it to my computer and do it from there. Is there any way to make the app download music from the cloud to my SD card rather than the internal storage?

Answer (score 4):

Manually moving files as suggested by Michael above works (I use Ghost Commander on my device), but today I found the [Amazon MP3 Mover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thunkmonkey.mp3mover) app.

It automatically moves the files to the folder you specify on your SD card *as they download* and then the Amazon MP3 player app (or Apollo or whatever else you might use) finds them in their new location.

I just downloaded it a few minutes ago and am testing it. So far so good!

Comment: On first launch, once you select the destination folder, it automatically moves your existing Amazon MP3 files from their originally location in your internal storage as well. Big plus!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're out of luck. The app doesn't support changing the location and the filesystem doesn't support soft links. I suggest you contact Amazon and suugest they add the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an app called ES File Manager and it lets you move music that is downloaded to anywhere you like.  And then Amazon Mp3 will read it anywhere on your device.